# Transaction is not committed when spring boot application is run from java -jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-boot-jpa

We developed an application using maven spring-boot.

When we run project with NetDeans IDE, everything works fine. But when we build it and run it from java -jar command, it seems that working and do not do database updates. On the other hand, it can read from database.

We are using **@Transactional** annotations with Jpa repositories. When we set loggers to ALL level, we could see differences between debug logs and build logs.
Debug is handling Transactions with **org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager**, but build is not. Build is using **org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager**

As you can see below, logs have some differences 
Working one

```
[DEBUG] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,431 org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager getTransaction - Creating new transaction with name [com.sportbook.bets.services.BetsServices.updateScheduledTasks]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; 'transactionManager'
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,431 org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl openSession - Opening Hibernate Session.  tenant=null, owner=null
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,431 org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl <init> - Opened Session [4685449c-c855-4806-a2a0-9ae8cdcd3e10] at timestamp: 1576835432431
[DEBUG] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,432 org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager doBegin - Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(127972401PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
[DEBUG] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,432 org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl <init> - On TransactionImpl creation, JpaCompliance#isJpaTransactionComplianceEnabled == false
[DEBUG] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,432 org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl begin - begin
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,432 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor begin - Preparing to begin transaction via JDBC Connection.setAutoCommit(false)
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,459 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor begin - Transaction begun via JDBC Connection.setAutoCommit(false)
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,460 org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl afterBeginCallback - ResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl#afterBeginCallback
[DEBUG] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,460 org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager doBegin - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@640b7957]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,460 org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager bindResource - Bound value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@67406405] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] to thread [default_task_executor_thread1]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,460 org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager bindResource - Bound value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@7c8d5edd] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@6f59896c] to thread [default_task_executor_thread1]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,460 org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager initSynchronization - Initializing transaction synchronization
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,460 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor prepareTransactionInfo - Getting transaction for [com.sportbook.bets.services.BetsServices.updateScheduledTasks]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,460 org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager bindResource - Bound value [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$DefaultCrudMethodMetadata@7e8e7c41] for key [public abstract java.lang.Object org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.save(java.lang.Object)] to thread [default_task_executor_thread1]
[DEBUG] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,461 org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource getTransactionAttribute - Adding transactional method 'save' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,461 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory doGetBean - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,461 org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager getResource - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@7c8d5edd] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@6f59896c] bound to thread [default_task_executor_thread1]
[DEBUG] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,461 org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager doGetTransaction - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(127972401PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,461 org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager getResource - Retrieved value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@67406405] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] bound to thread [default_task_executor_thread1]
[DEBUG] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,461 org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager handleExistingTransaction - Participating in existing transaction
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,461 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor prepareTransactionInfo - Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,464 org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults <init> - Getting BeanInfo for class [com.sportbook.bets.entities.ScheduledTasksLog]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,465 org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults <init> - Caching PropertyDescriptors for class [com.sportbook.bets.entities.ScheduledTasksLog]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,466 org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults <init> - Found bean property 'class' of type [java.lang.Class]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,466 org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults <init> - Found bean property 'id' of type [java.lang.Integer]
```

Not working one

```
[DEBUG] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,177 org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager getTransaction - Creating new transaction with name [com.sportbook.bets.services.BetsServices.updateScheduledTasks]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; 'transactionManager'
[DEBUG] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,177 org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager doBegin - Acquired Connection [HikariProxyConnection@32188486 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@1dc5318] for JDBC transaction
[DEBUG] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,177 org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager doBegin - Switching JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@32188486 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@1dc5318] to manual commit
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,201 org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager bindResource - Bound value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@13277ad] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] to thread [default_task_executor_thread2]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,201 org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager initSynchronization - Initializing transaction synchronization
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,201 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor prepareTransactionInfo - Getting transaction for [com.sportbook.bets.services.BetsServices.updateScheduledTasks]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,201 org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager bindResource - Bound value [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$DefaultCrudMethodMetadata@1b7705] for key [public abstract java.lang.Object org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.save(java.lang.Object)] to thread [default_task_executor_thread2]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,201 org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager getResource - Retrieved value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@13277ad] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] bound to thread [default_task_executor_thread2]
[DEBUG] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,201 org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager handleExistingTransaction - Participating in existing transaction
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,201 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor prepareTransactionInfo - Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]
[DEBUG] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,201 org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils doGetTransactionalEntityManager - Opening JPA EntityManager
```

I could not place all log outputs, but i think these small parts could provide some aspect. Any idea why this can happen?

**UPDATE**

My datasource configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "com.appdomain.testApp.repositories",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "testAppEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager"
)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TestAppDataSourceConfig {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.data1")
public DataSourceProperties testAppDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource testAppDataSource() {
    DataSourceProperties testAppDataSourceProperties = testAppDataSourceProperties();
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .driverClassName(testAppDataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName())
            .url(testAppDataSourceProperties.getUrl())
            .username(testAppDataSourceProperties.getUsername())
            .password(testAppDataSourceProperties.getPassword())
            .build();
}

@Bean
@Primary
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    EntityManagerFactory factory = testAppEntityManagerFactory().getObject();
    return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
}

@Bean(name="testAppEntityManagerFactory")
@Primary
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean testAppEntityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(testAppDataSource());
    factory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.appdomain.testApp.entities"});
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show-sql", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql"));
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
    factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
    return factory;

}

@Bean
@Primary
public DataSourceInitializer testAppDataSourceInitializer() {
    DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(testAppDataSource());
    dataSourceInitializer.setEnabled(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.data1.initialize", Boolean.class, false));
    return dataSourceInitializer;
}
}
```

My transactional service method:

```
@Transactional("transactionManager")
public ScheduledTasksLog updateScheduledTasks(ScheduledTasksLog scheduledTasksLog) {
    return scheduledTasksLogRepository.save(scheduledTasksLog);
}

@Transactional("transactionManager")
public ScheduledTasksLog getScheduledTasksLogByTaskName(String taskName) {
    return scheduledTasksLogRepository.findByTaskName(taskName);
}
```

My entity repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ScheduledTasksLogRepository  extends 
JpaRepository<ScheduledTasksLog, Integer> {
ScheduledTasksLog findByTaskName(String taskName);

}
```

My appsetting.properties:

```
jms.enabled=true

debug=true

spring.datasource.auto-commit=false

spring.datasource.data1.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.data1.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xx?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.data1.username=
spring.datasource.data1.password=
spring.datasource.data1.initialize=true

spring.datasource.data2.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.data2.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.data2.username=
spring.datasource.data2.password=
spring.datasource.data2.initialize=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database=default

eureka.client.enabled=false

# port
server.port=8667

proxyclient.baseuri =http://localhost:9999

spring.batch.job.enabled=false

spring.batch.initialize-schema=always

spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

My scheduled task that calls transactional service methods:

```
@EnableAsync
@Component
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.domain.message")
@EnableScheduling
public class ScheduledTasks {



@Autowired
private Sender sender;

@Autowired
private TestService testService;

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Async
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 40000)
public void testtask() {
    try {
        logger.info("The time is now:" + dateFormat.format(new Date()));

        ScheduledTasksLog scheduledTasksLog = testService.getScheduledTasksLogByTaskName("testtask");
        long interval = 0;
        if (scheduledTasksLog != null) {
            interval = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(Math.abs(new Date().getTime() - scheduledTasksLog.getLastRunDate().getTime()), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            interval += 3;
            scheduledTasksLog.setLastRunDate(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
        } else {
            interval = 180;
            scheduledTasksLog = new ScheduledTasksLog();
            scheduledTasksLog.setTaskName("testtask");
            scheduledTasksLog.setLastRunDate(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
        }

        testService.updateScheduledTasks(scheduledTasksLog);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

We use same application.properties file both with in debug and java -jar command.
JpaRepository handles transactions itself. We do not rollback or commit. How can we commit it manually?

Transaction commit part of logs:
Working one:

```
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,552 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor commit - Preparing to commit transaction via JDBC Connection.commit()
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,581 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor commit - Transaction committed via JDBC Connection.commit()
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,581 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor resetConnection - re-enabling auto-commit on JDBC Connection after completion of JDBC-based transaction
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,609 org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer doReceiveAndExecute - Consumer [ActiveMQMessageConsumer { value=ID:DESKTOP-LNDR73U-54344-1576835431439-1:1:1:1, started=true }] of session [ActiveMQSession {id=ID:DESKTOP-LNDR73U-54344-1576835431439-1:1:1,started=true} java.lang.Object@1012d727] did not receive a message
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,609 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor afterTransaction - LogicalConnection#afterTransaction
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,609 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl releaseResources - Releasing JDBC resources
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,609 org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl afterCompletionCallback - ResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl#afterCompletionCallback(true)
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,610 org.hibernate.resource.transaction.internal.SynchronizationRegistryStandardImpl tracef - SynchronizationRegistryStandardImpl.notifySynchronizationsAfterTransactionCompletion(3)
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,610 org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl afterTransactionCompletion - SessionImpl#afterTransactionCompletion(successful=true, delayed=false)
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,610 org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager triggerAfterCommit - Triggering afterCommit synchronization
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,610 org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager clearSynchronization - Clearing transaction synchronization
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,610 org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager triggerAfterCompletion - Triggering afterCompletion synchronization
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,610 org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager doUnbindResource - Removed value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@7c8d5edd] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@6f59896c] from thread [default_task_executor_thread1]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,610 org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager doUnbindResource - Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@67406405] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] from thread [default_task_executor_thread1]
[DEBUG] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,610 org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager doCleanupAfterCompletion - Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(127972401PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[com.domain.testapp.entities.ScheduledTasksLog#2]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] after transaction
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,610 org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl closeWithoutOpenChecks - Closing session [4685449c-c855-4806-a2a0-9ae8cdcd3e10]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,610 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl close - Closing JDBC container [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl@18320c9f]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,610 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl releaseResources - Releasing JDBC resources
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,611 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl close - Closing logical connection
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,611 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl releaseResources - Releasing JDBC resources
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,611 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl close - Logical connection closed
```

Not working one:

```
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,229 org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor extract - extracted value ([lastrund2_2_0_] : [TIMESTAMP]) - [2019-12-20 08:00:06.0]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,229 org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor extract - extracted value ([taskname3_2_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [testtask]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,229 org.hibernate.loader.Loader processResultSet - Done processing result set (1 rows)
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,229 org.hibernate.loader.Loader initializeEntitiesAndCollections - Total objects hydrated: 1
[DEBUG] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,229 org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad doInitializeEntity - Resolving associations for [com.domain.testapp.entities.ScheduledTasksLog#2]
[DEBUG] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,229 org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad doInitializeEntity - Done materializing entity [com.domain.testapp.entities.ScheduledTasksLog#2]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,230 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl release - Releasing statement [HikariProxyPreparedStatement@32276991 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement: select scheduledt0_.id as id1_2_0_, scheduledt0_.lastrundate as lastrund2_2_0_, scheduledt0_.taskname as taskname3_2_0_ from scheduled_tasks scheduledt0_ where scheduledt0_.id=2]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,230 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl close - Closing result set [HikariProxyResultSet@20385840 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl@139168f]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,230 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl close - Closing prepared statement [HikariProxyPreparedStatement@32276991 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement: select scheduledt0_.id as id1_2_0_, scheduledt0_.lastrundate as lastrund2_2_0_, scheduledt0_.taskname as taskname3_2_0_ from scheduled_tasks scheduledt0_ where scheduledt0_.id=2]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,230 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl afterStatementExecution - Starting after statement execution processing [ON_CLOSE]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,230 org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext initializeNonLazyCollections - Initializing non-lazy collections
[DEBUG] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,230 org.hibernate.loader.Loader loadEntity - Done entity load
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,230 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor commitTransactionAfterReturning - Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,230 org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager doUnbindResource - Removed value [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$DefaultCrudMethodMetadata@1b7705] for key [public abstract java.lang.Object org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.save(java.lang.Object)] from thread [default_task_executor_thread2]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,230 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor commitTransactionAfterReturning - Completing transaction for [com.domain.testapp.services.testservice.updateScheduledTasks]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,231 org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager triggerBeforeCommit - Triggering beforeCommit synchronization
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,231 org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager triggerBeforeCompletion - Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,231 org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager doUnbindResource - Removed value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@1093840] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@155cf22] from thread [default_task_executor_thread2]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,231 org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl closeWithoutOpenChecks - Closing session [55b47b79-008e-4f4a-b6d7-4c33c302171e]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,231 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl close - Closing JDBC container [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl@afa702]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,231 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl releaseResources - Releasing JDBC resources
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,231 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl close - Closing logical connection
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,231 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl releaseResources - Releasing JDBC resources
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,231 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl close - Logical connection closed
[DEBUG] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,231 org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager processCommit - Initiating transaction commit
[DEBUG] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,231 org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager doCommit - Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [HikariProxyConnection@32188486 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@1dc5318]
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,253 org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager triggerAfterCommit - Triggering afterCommit synchronization
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,253 org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager clearSynchronization - Clearing transaction synchronization
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,254 org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager triggerAfterCompletion - Triggering afterCompletion synchronization
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,254 org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager doUnbindResource - Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@13277ad] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] from thread [default_task_executor_thread2]
[DEBUG] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,295 org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager doCleanupAfterCompletion - Releasing JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@32188486 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@1dc5318] after transaction
```

Comment: Please share the code.

Comment: Spring Boot allows for different application properties (or YML) per profile. Do you have multiple applicationn*.properties or application*.yml, which define different DB settings?

Comment: I added code. I hope it helps. @dassum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After days of trying different solutions i finally found solution.

Cause of this situation is that we use Spring Batch and it wires a jdbc transaction manager named "transactionManager". Our jpa repository entities could not be persisted in it. So we can not add or update to database.

Solution is that we named our primary transaction manager to "primaryTransactionManager" and use it in our services. Also we used it on spring batch step configuration. Everything works as expected.

TLDR: JPA entities does not work with DataSourceTransactionManager.

Comment: My solution was to create `JpaTransactionManager` instead of `DataSourceTransactionManager`.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed below the log entry from the working one.

```
[TRACE] 2019-12-20 10:50:32,459 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor begin - Transaction begun via JDBC Connection.setAutoCommit(false)
```

I noticed below the log entry from the not working one.

```
[DEBUG] 2019-12-20 10:45:27,177 org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager doBegin - Switching JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@32188486 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@1dc5318] to manual commit
```

So after comparing these two, I think the probable possible solutions to your problem are listed below.

1. Use `<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="true" />` in the persistence.xml

       (Use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23100888/why-is-hibernate-connection-autocommit-true-not-recommended-in-hibernate) and [this link](https://www.howtobuildsoftware.com/index.php/how-do/bSzU/hibernate-jpa-openjpa-jpa-21-spring-jpa-spring-jpa-no-transaction-set-autocommit-true) for more information)
2. Use this `spring.datasource.auto-commit=false` in application.properties and commit it from your code.

       (*Here is the answer to you why! I wonder you must be having one!*)

       Setting autoCommit to false is the right thing to do.

       All RDBMS that I know of commit the transaction at the end unless explicitly rolled back. Do you see a different behavior? If you suspect something is wrong, one option is to turn on logging in the database server, where you would be able to see the commit request.

Comment: What do you think about differences between beginning transactions with these two logs? It is same application, same local machine, same configs, but transaction handled totally different. I wonder what can cause this. org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager should not be seen in logs i assume. Because we use org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.